# Jmeter Web service Testing (HTTP Raw Request)

Tags: http, jmeter

How to test web services which is written in PHP as "HTTP Raw Request" , I tried J meter Raw request Plugins, but i donno what to give in Request Data, And Data File Path ????

Kindly Suggest me to go further in Jmeter !!!!

Comment: Do you have to test it as "HTTP Raw Request" only? Can't you test it using default features for testing web services?

Answer (score 1):

SOAP Web Services are talking XML. REST Web Services are accept and reply JSON.

For XML-based Web Service you should be using

- [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) to send a request itself
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - for correlation (extract dynamic values from response for re-using)
- [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) - for checking that response is expected

For REST-based Web Service following components are quite good:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - to send requests
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) - to hold `Content-Type` and any other headers
- [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via plugin) - for correlation
- [JSONPath Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) - for testing

Perhaps [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide can be a good place to start with.